# R regex - removing pattern from ends

Tags: regex, r

Suppose I have a string that looks like so:

```
x <- "NNNNAAAJNFHANFFADN"
```

How would I only remove the N's from the ends to get:

```
"AAAJNFHANFFAD"
```

Comment: @akrun this would leave the `N` which exists before last `N`

Comment: it must be `sub('^N*(.*?)N*$', '\\1', x)` . But it's unnecesasry to match the inbetween characters.  It somehow decreases the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just match and remove the `N`'s which exists at the start or at the end through `gsub`.

```
gsub("^N+|N+$", "", x)
```

- `^N+` matches one or more `N`'s which exists at the start.
- `|` Alternation operator.
- `N+$` Matches one or more N's which exists at the end.

**Example:**

```
> x <- "NNNNAAAJNFHANFFADN"
> gsub("^N+|N+$", "", x)
[1] "AAAJNFHANFFAD"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gsub("^N*([A-Z]*?)N*$", "\\1", x)
```

You can use `\1` to backreference here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/66

Answer (score 2):

Use as

```
gsub("(^N{1,}|N{1,}$)","",x)
```

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/69

Comment: This will remove only the last `N`.Also if there are spaces this would not work.`NNNNABCNNN` or `NNNABCNN ASSSSSSSSSASNNN`

Comment: @vks updated it thanks for referring such conditions